# How to Add a Character to the Beginning of Each Word?

Tags: regex, vba

I am using the `RegExp` object in VBA. I have a string and would like to add a `$` character to the beginning of each word.

For example, if my string is:

```
dog cat 1 rrr
```

I would like to convert it to:

```
$dog $cat $1 $rrr
```

In `RegExp` I learned that you should use `$1` instead of `\1` to indicate a capturing group.
I tried the following VBA code.

```
Dim newString as String
Dim reg_exp As New RegExp
reg_exp.Pattern = "(\b\w+\b)"
reg_exp.IgnoreCase = True
reg_exp.Global = True

newString = reg_exp.Replace("dog cat 1 rrr", "\$$1")
```

In the replacement string I used `\\$$1` where `\\$` indicates `$` and `$1` indicates a capturing group.

The result was:

```
\\$1 \\$1 \\$1 \\$1 \\$1
```

Can anyone help me with the proper regular expression to use?

Comment: If you are using [tag:vbscript] and not [tag:vba] not sure how you've tried the code as `As String` alone would cause it to error. Remove all references to `As <DataType>`. You would also new to explicitly instantiate `RegExp` like `Set reg_exp = New RegExp`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I didn't give all the background since I didn't think it was needed.  I'm using VBScript syntax inside a program written in VBA.

Comment: I have no idea why it is closed as typo/not repro. It is perfectly repro in Excel VBA. Besides, the replacement clearly needs at least one fix, and the regex pattern needs optimizing.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it was tagged [tag:vbscript] but and talks about [tag:vbscript] in the question but the code is clearly not [tag:vbscript] but in fact now confirmed by the OP to be [tag:vba]. Maybe you should have just pointed it to one of your other numerous RegEx pattern answers.

Comment: @Lankymart This is  my first VBA regex related answer with the explanation how to refer to the whole match from the replacement pattern and fix the dollar symbol issue there.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew have adjusted the question to remove the references to [tag:vbscript] all over the place and voted to re-open. Adding [tag:vbscript] just confuses those who don't understand the difference between the syntaxes. While `RegExp` is part of the VBScript Regular Expression Library it's available to [tag:vba] through automation and [tag:vbscript] has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Lankymart Fine. I just wanted to stress the fact that the issue OP has is not with the VBScript or VBA, it is a purely regex issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to match word boundaries on both ends of `\w+`, they are there implicitly.

Also, no need to wrap the whole pattern with capturing parentheses, since you can always use `$&` backreference in the replacement pattern to refer to this whole match value.

And the most important bit: to use a literal dollar symbol inside a replacement pattern, you need to escape it with another dollar sign, `$$`.

Use

```
reg_exp.Pattern = "\w+"
```

and

```
newString = reg_exp.Replace("dog cat 1 rrr", "$$$&")
```

Comment: Hi Wiktor, I now have a slightly different need and wonder if you can help.  I have a string and would like to add a $ character to the beginning of each word.  However, if the word is followed by a ( character I don't want to add the $ character.  So: dog cat( horse would be converted to: $dog cat( $horse.  Since "cat" was followed by "(" I don't want to add $ to the beginning of the word.  Is it possible to do this?  Thanks so much!

Comment: @CurtisD `reg_exp.Pattern = "\w+(?!\w*\()"`